# Annotate Tool: Visible Every Frame?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, annotation

I'm having a problem where I want the annotate tool strokes to be visible every frame.  However, it appears that it is only being visible for the frame I drew it on.  How can I make it visible every frame?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  The top tab of the 3D view has Annotation tool information, and if you hit the "Note" drop-down, it has a field that says what frame the annotation was drawn on, and says either "locked" or "unlocked."
If you click on the field you can set it to "locked," and the drawing will now appear every frame.